# Looking for collision detection library for Java

Tags: java, collision-detection

I'm looking for a library which either supports boundary boxes, with rotation and scaling. I come across a lot of information about boundary boxes which do not rotate in either axis, however I do need rotation and scaling.

I know jBullet has it, however jBullet needs additional dynamic linking libraries to run, which I am not too keen of. This would be my second choice I guess.

Documentation is welcome as well, however I figure it is apparently hard to achieve this and I do have limited time.

Comment: A Google search for "_java collision detection library_" turns up lots of candidates. Are you looking for 2D, 3D, or arbitrary dimension?

Comment: Most I've come across are 2D, I am looking for 3D specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [Java 3D](http://java3d.java.net/). It includes 3D collision detection. I haven't looked at the sources at all, but I'm pretty sure it's not pure Java. I believe that the distribution includes quite a bit of native code, as there are different download binaries for different environments.

You can see an example of Java 3D collision detection [here](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/java3d/collision-detection-with-java3d.html).

Comment: I might be able to do what I want with the use of raytracing, do you happen to know if it runs as light as I think it does? I have a lot of shapes which normally cannot be displayed realtime due to their quantity.

Comment: @RobotRock - Sorry, I don't have much experience with it.